# Modularizar formularios de cadastro no JSF é possível?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

A questão é o seguinte... embora o problema não envolva JPA/ORM eu acho interessante contextualizar.

Meu projetinho possúi uma @Entity **Endereco** e como o nome sugere se trata de uma entidade responsável por armazenar dados relacionados a endereco imobiliario, desta maneira, diversas outras Entities fazem relacionamento com esta primeira, como por exemplo a classe Cliente e a classe Editora, etc... (Pois uma editora possúi um endereco real, assim como um cliente)

Eu pensei então que talvez fosse possível criar uma espécie de VIEW no JSF chamada "view-endereco.xhtml" e ela conteria todos os inputs que alimentam uma entidade do tipo endereco, assim eu poderia dar um INCLUDE nessa view  e carrega-la aonde quer que seja necessário preencher cadastro de endereco.

Porém entrei num seguinte dilema...

Cada formulário do JSF é atrelado a um ManagedBean, certo? Sendo assim, se eu implementar um cadastro de editora eu terei :

1. Uma @Entity **Editora**
2. Um @ManagedBean **EditoraBean**
3. E um XHTML cadastro-editora.xhtml

Meu XHTML cadastro-editora.xhtml iria dar um include na view responsável pelo **endereco** certo?

E como entao eu faria para associar os atributos do objeto **editoraBean.editora.endereco** aos VALUES dos inputs JSF da "view-endereco.xhtml" ?

Para ilustar, imaginem uma página assim:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
            <p:fieldset id="basic" legend="Editora" style="margin-bottom:20px">
              <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                  <p:outputLabel value="Nome: " for="txtEditora" />
                  <p:inputText id="txtEditora" value="#editoraBean.editora.nomeEditora}" />
              </h:panelGrid>
            </p:fieldset>

            <ui:include src="/restricted/fragments/contato.xhtml" />
            <ui:include src="/restricted/fragments/endereco.xhtml" />
     </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Compreendem? Afinal de contas, como pretendo modularizar essa view nao posso associar os values dos inputs dela ao **editoraBean**, mas gostaria de associa-los nem que fosse transmitindo o objeto ENDERECO via parametro para a view e depois recuperando os valores da view para dar submit na pagina de editora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa Cleiton, no meu sistema eu fiz algo neste sentido, também com endereço. A única diferença que eu vi da minha ideia para seu exemplo é que eu utilizei taglibs (https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-tags-in-jsf-2-0/).

ficando a minha tag:

```
<sga:enderecoListagem pessoa="#{empresaController.entidade}" />
```

no lugar do seu:

```
<ui:include src="/restricted/fragments/endereco.xhtml" />
```

e para o código da listagem de endereço, o acesso é feito da seguinte maneira:

```
<ui:component>
    <p:dataTable id="enderecoLista" value="#{enderecoController.registrosDaPessoa(pessoa)}"
        paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" var="endereco" paginator="true" rows="3"
        lazy="true" emptyMessage="Sem endereços!">
        (...) colunas
    </p:dataTable></ui:component>
```

perceba que o atributo `pessoa` da tag `sga:enderecoListagem` será repassado para o meu componente, e então utilizado no meu controller de endereços através do método `enderecoController.registrosDaPessoa(pessoa)`.

Espero ter ajudado em algo.